# Running PVS-Studio on a C# project on Linux gives weird output file format

Tags: c#, linux, pvs-studio

The analysis of my C# project outputs a file in an (to me) unknown file format. I would like to convert the output of the analysis to fullhtml with `plog-converter`, but this tool does not understand the generated analysis output. The output looks like [this (pastebin link)](https://pastebin.com/qUbg3E2D).

I have setup both the pvs core and dotnet package. Running `./pvs-studio-dotnet -t ~/Desktop/pvs-test/pvs-test.csproj -o analysis -r` seems to work, the exit code is 0. After converting the analysis output to fullhtml with `plog-converter`, the page looks like this:

[image]

which does not seem correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, plog-converter doesn't work with plog files.
If you want to avoid this restriction, you can get the report in the json format. To do this, run **pvs-studio-dotnet** the following way:

```
pvs-studio-dotnet -t ~/Desktop/pvs-test/pvs-test.csproj -o analysis.json -r
```

As a result, you'll get the PVS-Studio report in the json format.

After that you can convert it into fullhtml:

```
plog-converter -t fullhtml -o ./fullhtml_folder analysis.json
```

Comment: This has worked, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Zero code means that the analyzer couldn't find anything suspicious in your code. Perhaps, that's because some diagnostic rules are disabled or you've marked existing warnings as false alarms.
It seems like something is wrong with the plog-converter utility.